# Explain equality $F(n)=2^{n-1} \cdot 1 \cdot 3 \dots(2n-3)=\frac{(2n-2)!}{(n-1)!}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

$F(n)=2^{n-1} \cdot 1 \cdot 3 \dots(2n-3)=\frac{(2n-2)!}{(n-1)!}$

Any thouts how to prove this equality?

**Thanks**

Comment: Use induction on $n.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
2^{n - 1} \cdot 1 \cdot 3 \cdot \ldots \cdot (2n - 5) (2n - 3) & = 2^{n - 1} \cdot \frac{1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdots \ldots \cdot (2n - 5)(2n - 4)(2n - 3)(2n - 2)}{2 \cdot 4 \cdot \ldots \cdot (2n - 4)(2n - 2)} \\
 & = 2^{n - 1}\frac{(2n - 2)!}{2^{n - 1} \cdot 1 \cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot (n - 2)(n - 1)} \\
 & = \frac{(2n - 2)!}{(n - 1)!}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Look first at a simple case, for instance $n=5$: you have
$$
F(5)=2^4\cdot 1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7
$$
Insert the even numbers up to $8$, multiplying and dividing:
$$
F(5)=2^4\,\frac{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 8}
  {2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdot 8}
$$
The numerator is $8!=(2\cdot 5-2)!$ and the denominator can be rewritten as $2^4\cdot 1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4=2^4\cdot4!$, by collecting $2$ from each factor. The factors $2^4$ cancel with each other and you remain with
$$
F(5)=\frac{8!}{4!}
$$

Now the general case is the same, but maybe using induction is better:
\begin{align}
F(n+1)
&=2^n\cdot1\cdot 3\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n-3)\cdot(2n-1) \\[6px]
&=2\cdot (2n-1)\cdot F(n) \\[6px]
&=2\cdot(2n-1)\cdot\frac{(2n-2)!}{(n-1)!} &&\text{induction hypothesis}
\\[6px]
&=2\cdot(2n-1)\cdot\frac{2n}{2n}\cdot\frac{(2n-2)!}{(n-1)!}
  &&\text{insert the even factors} \\[6px]
&=2\frac{(2n-2)!\cdot(2n-1)\cdot(2n)}{(2n)\cdot(n-1)!}
  &&\text{rearrange the numerator} \\[6px]
&=2\frac{(2n)!}{(2n)\cdot(n-1)!}
  &&\text{recognize the factorial} \\[6px]
&=2\frac{(2n)!}{2(n\cdot(n-1)!)}
  &&\text{collect $2$ in the denominator} \\[6px]
&=\frac{(2n)!}{n\cdot(n-1)!} &&\text{cancel $2$} \\[6px]
&=\frac{(2n)!}{n!} &&\text{recognize the factorial} \\[6px]
\end{align}
The last expression is exactly what you get when you change $n$ into $n+1$ in $\frac{(2n-2)!}{(n-1)!}$.

Note that this is *the same* as Dominik's answer, but with all implicit passages worked out.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots (2n-3) = \dfrac{(2n-2)!}{2(n-1)\cdot2(n-2)\cdot\cdots 2(1)} = \dfrac{(2n-2)!}{2^{n-1}(n-1)!} 
\end{align}
Therefore,
$$ 2^{n-1}\cdot1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots (2n-3)=\dfrac{(2n-2)!}{(n-1)!}$$

Answer (score 0):

this is simple:
$2^{n-1} \cdot 1\cdot3...(2n-3) \Rightarrow A = 1\cdot3...(2n-3) \Rightarrow A \times (2\cdot4\cdot6.....(2n)\cdot (2n-2)) = 1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot6...(2n-1)\cdot(2n-2)\cdot(2n-3) \Rightarrow A \times 2^{n-1}\cdot(n-1)!=(2n-3)! \Rightarrow 2^{n-1} \times A = \frac{(2n-3)!}{(n-1)!} $

Comment: Use "\cdot" instead of fullstop.